# Multiple Zabbix Dashboard's Integration

Tags: zabbix

Can we integrate multiple Zabbix Dashboards into a Single Dashboard for Monitoring?

Like i have an instance in X Location and other in Y Location. I need to show a dashboard to management with all the available triggers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a single Grafana with multiple [Zabbix](https://grafana.com/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app) datasources.
You can set up a single dashboard or multiple dashboards with graphs and trigger from multiple sources, quick host/item/server selection with templating etc...

Answer (score 0):

Below are the 2 solutions which i found to integrate different Zabbix environments.

1. Grafana tool need to be installed and all the Zabbix instances data need to be pushed to Grafana for visualization. In this method we are getting data from API.
2. For all the Zabbix database a web socket need to be built and push the data to a Redux store and built a React UI, so that only changed data will be available in the UI.